# LLVM, Expected Instruction?

Tags: c, assembly, llvm

I wrote the following short Assembly LLVM code (I know it's not efficent only for testing purposes):

```
define void @main() {
label_41:
%t22 = add i32 0, 0
label_43:
%t23 = add i32 0, 0
}
```

When I try to run it like this I get an error:

```
Downloads % /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/lli t02.out
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/lli: lli: t02.out:4:1: error: expected instruction opcode
label_43:
^
```

What's the problem, which opcode is missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A label in LLVM starts a new block. And each block must end with a [terminator instruction](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#terminator-instructions) such as `ret` or `br`.

LLVM is giving the error because it reached a label but the preceding block didn't end with a terminator instruction. To get this to compile, you need to add terminator instructions before `label_43:` and before the end of the function.

Comment: The error message could be worded better, IMHO.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It definitely could. Although I suppose it isn't a priority because LLVM IR isn't usually written by hand.